# "Whoops! /run/nordvpn/nordvpnd.sock not found" - Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, nordvpn

I used to connect to NordVPN from my Ubuntu 18.04 server, but I haven't used NordVPN for a few months. When I tried to connect to NordVPN now, it showed an error message saying

> Whoops! /run/nordvpn/nordvpnd.sock not found.

I referred to many articles, including NordVPN's official link, to fix this issue, but none of the suggested solutions worked for me. According to NordVPN's official link, the issue might be due to a permission problem, and I followed the below steps based on their suggestion:

```
sudo usermod -aG nordvpn $USER
```

Then I restarted the system, but it still didn't work. Others suggested restarting the nordvpnd service using the below commands:

```
sudo systemctl start nordvpnd.service
sudo systemctl enable nordvpnd.service
```

But this also didn't work for me.

Finally, I tried completely removing and then reinstalling NordVPN with the following commands:

**Uninstall:**

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove 'nordvpn*'
```

**Install:**

```
sh <(curl -sSf https://downloads.nordcdn.com/apps/linux/install.sh)
```

However, even after the fresh installation, I am facing the same problem with connecting to NordVPN.

Comment: Don't forget Ubuntu 18.04 LTS was the 2018-April release of Ubuntu, which had *five* years of *standard* support life; ie. was expected to be EOSS last month (April 2023).  Canonical have extended life until 31-May-2023, but you can use `ubuntu-support-status` to confirm if you've *enabled* ESM/Pro support to extend your status. You should be planning on upgrading your system asap if you're not opting to use ESM/Pro

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When I checked the status of the NordVPN service using the command:

> sudo systemctl status nordvpnd.service

it threw an error message stating **Failed with result 'exit-code'**. To debug the issue, I used the command:

> journalctl -u nordvpnd.service

which displayed the following message:

```
nordvpnd[2915]: /usr/sbin/nordvpnd: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by nordvpnd)
```

I then checked the GLIBC version on my system using the command:

> apt list -a libc6

and found that the GLIBC version was **2.27-3ubuntu1.6**, which is lower than the expected version by NordVPN. I realized that I usually run the `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` commands twice a week, and it had updated the NordVPN version on my system.

I had two options, either to upgrade my GLIBC version or downgrade the NordVPN to the last known working version. After researching the possibility of upgrading the GLIBC version, I found that many users faced system crash problems or other complexities, so I decided to downgrade the NordVPN.

I found the NordVPN releases for Linux at the link https://repo.nordvpn.com/deb/nordvpn/debian/pool/main/, which provided the version release details.

I performed the following steps to install the older version of NordVPN and successfully connected to it!

**Uninstalled NordVPN**

> sudo apt-get --purge remove 'nordvpn*'

**Installed NordVPN:**

> wget -qnc https://repo.nordvpn.com/deb/nordvpn/debian/pool/main/nordvpn-release_1.0.0_all.deb

> sudo dpkg -i nordvpn-release_1.0.0_all.deb

> sudo apt update

**Installed specific version (For me 3.14.2)**

> sudo apt install nordvpn=3.14.2

**Since I was not sure which older version would work for me, I decided to install version 3.14.2. If you remember which version was working for you, you can try installing that version instead.**

**Enabled NordVPN services on boot**

> sudo systemctl enable --now nordvpnd.service

**Checked the status of the NordVPN service**

> sudo systemctl status nordvpnd.service

There were no more errors related to GLIBC and all working as expected!!

There will be the possibility of upgrading the Nordvpn when you run upgrade command and keep in mind to ignore the upgrade of Nordvpn.

*I wanted to share my solution to help others who may be facing a similar issue. However, I want to note that downgrading or using an older version of a VPN may have potential consequences related to security. It's important to always use the latest version of a VPN to ensure that the best security and privacy features are in place. If you do decide to use an older version, it's important to understand the potential risks and make an informed decision.*

Comment: Hell Artur. Your solution worked great in my case. Thanks for your effort. The only difference was that I have to ``wget nordvpn_3.14.2`` and then install.